# SwiftUI: NavigationView inside TabView height not occupying the fullscreen

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I seeing an unexpected UI issue in my SwiftUI project when I add a `NavigationView` inside a `TabView`.

Here's my code,

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(0..<30) { i in
                            Text("Hello World")
                                .padding()
                                .frame(minWidth: .zero, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        }
                    }
                }.background(Color.red)
                .navigationTitle("Home View")
            }.background(Color.green)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                TabItem(title: "Explore", systemImage: selectedTab == 0 ? "house.fill" : "house")
            }.tag(1)
            
            ExploreView()
                .background(Color.red)
                .tabItem {
                    TabItem(title: "Explore", systemImage: selectedTab == 1 ? "safari.fill" : "safari")
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my scene delegate code,

```swift
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo _: UISceneSession, options _: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            self.window = window
        }

        let host = UIHostingController(rootView: RootView())
        window?.rootViewController = host
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

[image: NavigationView-TabView-ScrollView]

The height of the `ScrollView`(which resides inside the `NavigationView`) is not occupying the full screen. I tried all the tricks(padding, frame, `GeometryReader`, ...), but no luck. I couldn't figure out what am I doing wrong here, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more info and/or complete the code so that it is self contained? My own quick test (creating Text based stubs for non-specified views like TabItem) worked as expected (no gap at bottom). Simulator versions, devices, or anything else to help others observe the issue would be helpful.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. I'm using SwiftUI in UIKit (in an existing project). I tried both suggested answers, but neither is working for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answers and for offering to help me.

I accidentally comment `UITabBar`'s appearance logic, *which* fixed that problem. I'm not sure if this is a bug in SwiftUI or I'm missing something. Anyhow, commenting this following appearance fixed the issue,

```swift
// UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false   <<-- Remove this
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you discover what was it?

Comment: but if you remove that then the navigation view extends behind the tab bar... so it's not a solution

Answer (score 1):

It is inside safe area, you need to ignore it

```
}.background(Color.red)
.navigationTitle("Home View")
.ignoresSafeArea()             // << here !!
```